# Laravel 5 Error on Maintenance Mode

Tags: laravel

I get an error when setting Laravel in maintenance mode

```
HttpException in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 39:

in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 39
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 101
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 115
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 84
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 53
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is expected behaviour. You need to catch that exception and respond to it however you see fit.

More info:

http://laravel.com/docs/master/installation#maintenance-mode

Laravel will look for the following file and display it if found:

```
resources/views/errors/503.blade.php
```

Comment: i re-install my laravel, and fix it . Thanks for your answer @joachim